# Hazelcast Map key length is different after restarting it

Tags: java, hbase, hazelcast

Im working on a project in which I'm using Hazelcast (version : 1.9.3.1) as our system's distributed cache and writes' behind all that cached data into the Hbase. But I'm facing a very strange problem. When I cache my data using Hazelcast map using string key and write behind it to Hbase. And restart my Hazelcast and then try to retrieve data using key after 
Hazelcast loads all the data from Hbase to Map. I have noticed that the length of key is now different from its previous length when it was stored into the Map.

For example Real key : "ada1:user1"
            Malformed Key: "ada1:user1               " 
            Real key Length= 9,Malformed Key Length= 10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there may be a problem on storing by HBase. Maybe HBase fills your String with spaces.

Have you checked that?

Also have you checked store implementations of MapLoader interface?

Comment: I  have checked so many tests, analyzed that for some strange reason Hbase is causing extra spaces. Hcast Mapstore is working fine.